# Sorted() in lambda's not working as intended - Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8

While learning lambda's, I found sorted method is not working as intended.

The following program is giving  `[1, 33, 2, 4, 5, 11]` as an output, however I am expecting a sorted output.

Strange thing is when I replace the `[33, 2, 1, 4, 5, 11]` with `[ 3, 1,2, 4, 5]` every thing works fine and I got the sorted output as expected.

```
public class Test {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(33, 2, 1, 4, 5, 11);
            Set<Integer> set = list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toSet());
            System.out.println(set);
        }
      }
```

Please help me understand this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should collect to a `Collection` which preserves ordering which a `HashSet` in role by the default implementation of `toSet`  doesn't:

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))
```

Comment: But why it is working for  3, 1,2, 4, 5

Comment: 'Cos ... luck.  Or more precisely, a deterministic but serendipitous ordering that is determined the way that `Integer:hashCode` is calculated + the way that the (default) `HashSet` is being populated.

Comment: @Joker That could just be a coincidence along with the fact as pointed by Stephen the hashcode implementation of the Integer. For one such experiment, you can remove the `sorted` operation with the input `3, 1,2, 4, 5` and verify the output if it would just remain the same as you find with the `sorted` operation.